# how can I have a warning in between opt-in page and thank you page

Tags: affiliate, clickbank

I have Namecheap as my domain. And Bluehost.
have not connected autoresponder yet.

So how do I get a warning page after
they opt-in? before the clcikbank vendor presentation begins.

Thank you is custom URL of a clcikbank-link to a vendor.
Affiliate marketing.
But all Autoresponders only have two pages"
I need something in-between.
What are my options. If a developer has code where do I
place it in thank you page? OR What else can I do ? thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. This is a site for questions about software development. In your case you seem to be asking a question that is related to ClickBank which is an affiliate marketing solution but at least to me it is not clear how this relates to actual code. See also this topic --> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - please read it and see if you can rephrase your question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.